# Getting rid of the printer spooling dialog box during programmatic printing

Tags: printing, ms-word, wsh

The following is the CScript script I use for the programmatic printing of a Word document.

```
var err = 0;
var app = WScript.CreateObject("Word.Application");
try {
  var filename = WScript.Arguments(0);
  var enc = (filename.toLowerCase().indexOf(".txt") >= 0) || (filename.toLowerCase().indexOf(".htm")) ? 65001 : 1252;
  var objDoc = app.Documents.Open(filename, false, true, false, " ", " ", false, " ", " ", 0, enc, true, false, 0, true);
  objDoc.PrintOut(false, false, 0, "", "", "", 0);
} catch (e) {
  err = 1;
} finally {
  app.Quit(0);
}
WScript.Quit(err);
```

How can I modify it to prevent the spooling dialog box from being displayed? (Is this even possible?) A screen capture of what I mean by "spooling dialog box" is at [http://imgur.com/qqtib.png](https://imgur.com/qqtib.png).

Answer (score 1):

We used to do a very similar type of thing when trying to print Word documents. We now use [Aspose.Words for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx). It works great. Much more control over printing without the problems of loading word.